# how to convert string to Time using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have string like this `"8:00 Am"` I need to convert it into time format how can i do that using jquery

Comment: Time format in the sense?

Comment: now the 8:00 Am is in string format I want to convert it into the standard DateTime format using jquery

Comment: have you found expected output with te solution i've suggested alen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/test/parseExact/index.html)

example

```
Date.parseExact("8:00 AM", "hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `date.js` then try

```
Date.parseExact("8:00 Am", "hh:mm tt");
```

This will give you date if you have loaded the javascript correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vuURb/25/)**

```
 var time = Date.parse('8:00 AM');
 alert(time);
```